# Weblogic Apache Plugin and database connections

Tags: apache, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am new to the Apache plugin. How can it be configured to detect if my Weblogic server has a valid connection to the datasource and to take it out of the round-robin loop if it doesn't?

If the plugin does not do this is there another way?

Thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this using the web server plugin - the plugin is only able to connect to the WLS server and not the database/datasource.

the mechanism you're looking for is to set Test Connection and Retries to the database and it will suspend and retest to an unhealthy connection based on the way its configured.

See more on the [Oracle docs.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13737/ds_tuning.htm#i1195917)